# NotifyIcon DoubleClick events aren't fired

Tags: c#, events, notifyicon

Currently working on notifyIcon, I followed this tutorial in order to set Minimize to Tray option.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27599/Minimize-window-to-system-tray

So when the user click on Window minimize button, it makes the tray icon appear.

This tutorial work fine, when I have only one form. When I instantiate a new form  (different from the main one) that contains a timer in it, the notifyIcon DoubleClick event isn't fired, so the main form can't pop-up.

Do anyone the reason of this behaviour? Is it possible to see events in real-time without a adding a breakpoint?

EDIT:

it seems that it's not a timer problem. In my second form, I'm using AttachThreadInput (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956(v=vs.85).aspx) function, and when I comment it, the doubleClick event is trigerred. So I think the problem is because I attach another thread to the second thread form. But I don't understand why it blocks the event in the main form...

Comment: You'll need to post a snippet, the least amount of code that reproduces this problem.

Comment: I found the origin of the problem. See my first Edit.